# How to make powershell be less verbose on errors?

Tags: powershell

For instance, consider the following console transcript:

```
PS C:\dev\windows> rmdir -Recurse .\bin
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\dev\windows\bin\DotNet\Debug\Implementation\Common.DTO.XML: Access to the path 'Common.DTO.XML' is denied.
At line:1 char:6
+ rmdir <<<<  -Recurse .\bin
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (Common.DTO.XML:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
Remove-Item : Directory C:\dev\windows\bin\DotNet\Debug\Implementation cannot be removed because it is not empty.
At line:1 char:6
+ rmdir <<<<  -Recurse .\bin
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Implementation:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotEmpty,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\dev\windows\bin\DotNet\Debug\Shunra.Common.Contract.XML: Access to the path 'Shunra.Common.Contract.XML' is denied.
At line:1 char:6
+ rmdir <<<<  -Recurse .\bin
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (Shunra.Common.Contract.XML:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\dev\windows\bin\DotNet\Debug\Shunra.Common.XML: Access to the path 'Shunra.Common.XML' is denied.
At line:1 char:6
+ rmdir <<<<  -Recurse .\bin
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (Shunra.Common.XML:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
Remove-Item : Directory C:\dev\windows\bin\DotNet\Debug cannot be removed because it is not empty.
At line:1 char:6
+ rmdir <<<<  -Recurse .\bin
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Debug:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotEmpty,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Remove-Item : Directory C:\dev\windows\bin\DotNet cannot be removed because it is not empty.
At line:1 char:6
+ rmdir <<<<  -Recurse .\bin
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (DotNet:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotEmpty,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Remove-Item : Directory C:\dev\windows\bin cannot be removed because it is not empty.
At line:1 char:6
+ rmdir <<<<  -Recurse .\bin
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\dev\windows\bin:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotEmpty,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

PS C:\dev\windows>
```

Now compare it with the ordinary shell (cmd.exe):

```
C:\dev\windows>rmdir /s/q bin
bin\DotNet\Debug\IMPLEM~1\Common.DTO.XML - Access is denied.
bin\DotNet\Debug\Shunra.Common.Contract.XML - Access is denied.
bin\DotNet\Debug\Shunra.Common.XML - Access is denied.

C:\dev\windows>
```

The difference is obvious and I like the laconicity of cmd.exe much much more than the verbosity of the powershell.

Can I have the same laconicity in powershell? If not for all the commands then maybe just for the Remove-Item, which I use often?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest result you can get is by changing the global $ErrorView value to "CategoryView". Another way is to create your own view.

Comment: Here's some source material for Shay's answer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/06/21/641010.aspx

Comment: @halr9000 - thanks for the info. If you arrange it as an answer I will be happy to credit you for that.